# Ubuntu 14.04 will not install or run from USB stick

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

Firstly, I hope that I am posting in the right place for the right thing this time. Please don't hammer me too much if what I am asking is not appropriate for this forum.

I have created a USB boot drive with Ubuntu 14.04.01 on it. I'm trying to install it on a Zoostorm Desktop machine purchase November 2013 - Zoostorm Desktop PC, AMD Elite DC A4-5300 3.4GHz, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD, DVDRW, AMD HD 7480D, Windows 8.1.

Basically I can't install Ubuntu on it or run Ubuntu from a boot USB for more than a few seconds/minutes (yesterday it was minutes, today it is seconds). Here's the problems and what I have tried so far (I'm trying not to miss anything out just in case it gives anyone an idea):

1. IMPORTANT: The new machine had been running Windows 8 without issue
   before I tried to install Ubuntu. There were never any problems when
   running Windows 8, hardware or otherwise.
2. As a result of the following problems with Ubuntu installations
   yesterday the machine reboots during install have damaged the
   windows 8 partition beyond repair/recovery. I was hoping to make the
   machine dual boot.
3. Although not an Ubuntu expert, I have set up lots of Ubuntu
   installations in the past (from about Ubuntu 6 - it was so long ago
   I'm not quite sure what the number was), mostly dual boots with
   windows but some just Ubuntu. I have set up and installed Ubuntu
   desktop machines, laptops and servers. I am used to having to work
   hard to get things like wireless drivers etc. working on laptops so
   I am familiar with difficult installations and setups.
4. I have spent over 14 hours so far trying to get Ubuntu to install on
   this machine.
5. I have tried the following using 2 different USB drives
6. I have recreated the USB image on the USB drives several times.
7. I have run "Check disk for defects".
8. Yesterday I couldn't run Ubuntu from the USB ("Try Ubuntu without
   installation") for more than than a few minutes before the machine
   reboots itself.
9. Today I only get to see the "Try Ubuntu" desktop for a few seconds
    before the machine reboots. When the machine reboots today I
    briefly get to see the number "92" in the bottom right hand corner
    for a few seconds then another number (too quick to see) then D7
    (on a black screen, white text nothing else on the screen). I have
    no idea what this means or why I am seeing it. Following this auto
    reboot I find that when it gets to the Ubuntu boot menu again that
    the mouse and keyboard have stopped working (both are USB). I have
    to power the machine down and restart before they will work again.
10. Yesterday I was able to boot to the "Try Ubuntu" desktop and start
     installation from there. However, after progressing down the Ubuntu
     install options the machine would eventually auto reboot at
     different places each time, sometimes when I was selecting install
     options, sometimes after Ubuntu had started installing/formatting.
11. If I choose to install Ubuntu now from the boot menu I see the
     ubuntu logo briefly then the screen goes black and after several
     seconds the machine reboots itself
12. I have tried with the Windows 8 part of the BIOS turned on and I
     have tried with all the Windows 8 boot features turned off (this
     includes turning off Fast Boot).
13. I have tried 3 different hard drives.

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions of what else I could try or what other information may help?

Thanks.

Comment: Just tried 12.04.05. Running from live CD I see the same problem. Have played around with BIOS settings (Widows 8, Fast Boot etc). I can now get to a EFI shell but that hasn't helped.

Comment: I just made a little progress. I plugged the HD (one of the 3 I have tried) to serial port 1 (was in 2). I can now get back to try ubuntu from live CD. I can then selection install, choose language, choose to install updates then about 30 seconds later the machine reboots again.

Comment: Trying 14.04.01 again. Check disk for defects works fine.

Comment: Trying the option to install ubuntu from Boot menu. Ubuntu logo appears, red/white dots cycle, get to see the choose language option for a few seconds, screen goes bland and eventually machine reboots with the number "92" in bottom right hand corner of a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got Ubuntu to install on the Zoostorm by adding `nomodeset` to the Live USB boot menu options as follows:

1. On the startup boot screen press <kbd>e</kbd>
2. Find the line ending `quiet splash` and add `nodemodeset` just
   before it.
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot (for me I have try before install selected before I pressed <kbd>e</kbd>)
4. Choose install Ubuntu from the desktop. (This will probably also
   work if you choose install Ubuntu from the startup menu, but I
   haven't tried it).
5. Wait for this install then choose "restart now". (NOTE: During the
   install my screen went black but pressing "any key" refreshed the
   screen - looks like a screen saver blank screen or something).
6. The machine then restarted and I saw the Ubuntu loading logo.
   Shortly after this the machine rebooted again. Restart the machine
   by turning it on and off again and hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> to
   ensure that you see the grub boot menu.
7. At the Ubuntu boot menu press <kbd>e</kbd> again and repeat steps 2. and 3.
8. You should then boot in to your Ubuntu install.
9. You will now need to permanently modify your kernel boot parameters
   (unless you are going to try and find the right video driver). To do
   this I installed Grub Customizer following [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/). From Grub Customizer choose the
   "General settings" tab and enter "nomodeset" in the kernel
   parameters before "quiet splash". Then hit the "Save" button.
10. Next reboot and check that you log in to Ubuntu without the machine
     rebooting itself.

    I got the above idea when looking at [Ubuntu forums this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132). According to this article:

    > Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video
    >   drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.